# SQL Pivot Data with Group

Tags: sql, linq, pivot

I have this query:

```
 SELECT TOP (1000) count([CallId]) as totalCalls
      ,[CallDirection]
      ,[AssignedWorkGroup]
      ,DATEPART(month, connectedDate) as SelectedMonth
 FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[calldetail_viw]
 where connectedDate > '2018-8-01'
 and localname='myaccountrep'
 and AssignedWorkGroup <>'-'
 group by assignedworkgroup,calldirection,DATEPART(month, connectedDate) 
 order by SelectedMonth,calldirection
```

which returns my data in columns

```
totalcalls, calldirection, assigned workgroup, selectedmonth
```

but I need my data

```
SelectedMonth, Assignedworkgroup, INBOUND, OUTBOUND, TotalCalls
```

So I need to pivot the two values in the calldirection field.  Can someone please show me how to modify my query - 
I actually need it in LINQ.
TIA!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation looks like it would do the trick.

Something along these lines...

```
SELECT
  selectedMonth,
  AssignedWorkgroup,
  SUM(CASE WHEN calldirection =  'INBOUND' THEN totalCalls ELSE 0 END)   AS INBOND,
  SUM(CASE WHEN calldirection = 'OUTBOUND' THEN totalCalls ELSE 0 END)   AS OUTBOND,
  SUM(totalCalls)                                                        AS totalCalls
FROM
(
  <yourquery>
)
  AS toPivot
GROUP BY
  selectedMonth,
  assignedWorkgroup
```

Comment: i converted to this:

      SELECT
      DATEPART(month, connectedDate) as SelectedMonth,
      AssignedWorkgroup,calldirection,
      SUM(CASE WHEN calldirection =  'INBOUND' THEN count(calldirection) 
      ELSE 0 END)   AS INBOND,
      SUM(CASE WHEN calldirection = 'OUTBOUND' THEN count(calldirection) 
     ELSE 0 END)   AS OUTBOND
      FROM [removed for brevity]
      GROUP BY
      DATEPART(month, connectedDate),
      assignedWorkgroup,calldirection

and I get error:
 Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.